# Image is not loading in Note 8

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image with demensions ‪13376x1728‬. I have created mdpi, hdpi, ... and so on different sized and placed all of them in proper folders.

I have tested with emulator (Galaxy S8) and Meizu M3s and everything is working great. BUT in NOTE 8, the image is not showing up.

[Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sBS86oFsrKsbLWtaLCGzkmSaawZafsaF)

I have tried to google but could not find anything. Any suggestions are welcome.

`res` hierarchy 
[image]

Comment: Please post a pic of res hierarchy of your drawable.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån posted.

Comment: I see that you don't have this pic in normal drawable folder, just place this pic in normal drawable folder or you can create another folder with `drawable-nodpi` folder name and add this image in that folder and try.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån tried. did not help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `drawable-nodpi`? If this also did not help, please post your xml and activity code. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Okay, All the best.